# how to Add search box in acf map?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with the advanced custom field plugin.
I created the Google map with the advanced custom field that can be displayed well on my site.
How can I add to the search box in map?
I need your help. Thank

Like the attached image:

[image: add search box in acf map]

Comment: The English can be improved, and I am not sure how to interprete the question

Comment: @sogoli did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the ACF plugin always put the search box on the top of the map.

If you really want to display the search box directement in the map, don't use ACF but directly the Google Maps API.